# Formula for estimates of multivariate linear regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-regression

Does anyone have links to a source which gives the mathematics behind how coefficients, standard error's and covariance structures are estimated in multivariate linear regression?

There are plenty of topics on stack about the differences between multivariate linear regression (> 1 outcome) and multivariable/multiple linear regression (> 1 predictor variable). However none have references to sources which detail the maths of how the coefficients and correlation structure are estimated for multivariate linear regression.

Googling this has proven to be more difficult than expected, as the terms are frequently incorrectly, and most sources I have found on multivariate linear regression, are actually detailing multivariable regression (> 1 predictor).

Comment: Hi: I can't say for sure because they're not handy but I would think that it would be in a multivariate stats text like johnson and wichern or mardia ?

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look in my library and see if they are available!

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.wustl.edu/~sawyer/handouts/multivar.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjH9qisuYztAhVPeKwKHTYaAuAQFjANegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw14ZBVAy5JCxa_LDtMkPog8

Comment: @AP30: You're welcome and . have a look but what BigBendRegion linked to looks pretty good so maybe the texts aren't necessary.

Comment: I've just had a look a the source from @BigBendRegion and it looks super relevant, thank you very much both

Comment: Hi, just to help clarify things, multivariate and multivariable are synonyms.

Comment: Wikipedia has some references https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model?wprov=sfti1